# How to plot stacked bar chart in highcharts with dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Hi i am working on highcharts stacked chart so here i am getting the data from api is like this:

```
[{
        name: "john",
        task: "Project - 1",
        units: 88.25,
      },
      {
        name: "john",
        task: "Others",
        units: 79.75,
      },
      {
        name: "joe",
        task: "Others",
        units: 120,
      },
      {
        name: "jane",
        task: "Others",
        units: 88.75,
      },
      {
        name: "jane",
        task: "Project - 1",
        units: 4,
      }

    ]
```

Here is the jsfiddle link [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/whgLnzj6/5/)

How to plot stacked bar chart with the dynamic data? TIA.

Comment: Hi @kishan, I am not sure in which way you want to present your data. Could check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k04wvndm/ and let me know if you want to achieve something like that or something different?

Comment: Yeah this is good but i want to see the legends as tasks like others, and project-1 and stacks will be john,joe...

Comment: This is how it should reflect http://jsfiddle.net/uav5nfjL/21/ the colors should be names how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to use `name` or `task` for series? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0stnjh2y/

Comment: Task as the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map your data to the series structure required by Highcharts and use x-axis with categories.

```
const series = [];
const categories = [];

data.forEach(function(dataEl) {
    const existingSeries = series.find(s => s.name === dataEl.name);
    const existingCategory = categories.find(c => c === dataEl.task);

    if (!existingCategory) {
        categories.push(dataEl.task);
    }

    if (existingSeries) {
        existingSeries.data.push([categories.indexOf(dataEl.task), dataEl.units]);
    } else {
        series.push({
            name: dataEl.name,
            data: [
                [categories.indexOf(dataEl.task), dataEl.units]
            ]
        });
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    xAxis: {
        categories,
        ...
    },,
    series
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lutyq4e6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data